# Is it possible in PostgreSQL to give a specific user or group on edit rights only to one schema?

Tags: postgresql, permissions, database-schema, postgresql-9.4, sql-grant

Is it possible in PostgreSQL to give a specific user or group on edit rights only to one schema?
I need the user to only change the objects in the schema. Similar to superuser rights, but only for one schema.

Thank for advance

Comment: You cannot allow a user to override all security checks in one schema only, as you seem to want. You'll have to give the user the required privileges for each object. `GRANT ... ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA ...` will help.

Comment: Created the table, under user2:
`CREATE TABLE testsch.weather3 (city varchar (80), temp_hi int, prcp real, date date);`
Performed under the superuser:
`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA testsch to user3;`
Under user3, the error is:
`ALTER TABLE testsch.weather3 ADD COLUMN description4 text;
ERROR: must be owner of relation weather3`

How to get around this?

Comment: create a function security definer that will set owner on any new object in that schema to your user. create an even trigger executing that function... ugly hack, but seems smplest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best setup in your case is probably the following.

Let's assume that the schema and the objects therein are owned by `object_owner` and the user that should have “superuser” privileges is called `wannabe`.

Then you can do:

```
ALTER ROLE wannabe NOINHERIT;
GRANT object_owner TO wannabe;
```

That allows `wannabe` to become `object_owner` by running

```
SET ROLE object_owner;
```

similar to using `su` in UNIX. Use `RESET ROLE` to step down again.