# Postgres access to everything in a database

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to create a user will full access to a database. However, the only way I'm able to accomplish this is the relatively hackish:

```
CREATE USER f WITH PASSWORD 'password';
ALTER user f with superuser;
```

If I do something like the following:

```
CREATE USER f WITH PASSWORD 'password';
grant all privileges on database "login" to f;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO f;
```

It still does not allow me to select data from an existing table:

```
$ psql --host=localhost --dbname=login --username=f
login=> select * from "user";
ERROR:  permission denied for relation user
```

How would I give a user "superuser" access to a single database?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible in PostgreSQL to give a specific user or group on edit rights only to one schema?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51481497/6464308).

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe thanks, in the above case then, is giving them superuser access overkill, or is that an acceptable way to do it?

Comment: In my opinion, it is always a mistake to give anybody but the DBA superuser privileges. In your particular case you *might* be missing privileges on schema `public`. If you want a real answer to your question, Try to come up with a self-contained test case that exhibits the problem, because what you are trying to do should work (by default, everybody is allowed access to the schema `public`). Perhaps `user` is no table, or it was defined *after* the `GRANT` statement.